# Reading ETOPO tiff images into numpy array (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, tiff

I'm trying to read one of these images in Python https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/relief/ETOPO2022/data/15s/15s_surface_elev_gtif/

They are greyscale tiff images. I managed to read them with the Pillow (PIL) library:

```
im = Image.open(filepath)
```

and all is well. I get something with dimensions 3600 x 3600, which seems reasonable.

Now I want to look at the pixel values so I try to create a numpy array:

```
imarray = numpy.array(im)
```

with various arguments, but I always end up with nothing (size = 1). Has anybody tried to read these images and successfully accessed the pixel values? Is the problem related to having 32 bit greyscale values?

I have also tried other ways, using imageio and cv2 libraries, but so far no luck. I'm relatively new to Python and these libraries, so maybe I'm heading in the wrong direction here. Has anyone tried and succeeded with these particular ones?

Comment: Since these are GeoTIFF files, use GDAL or [rasterio](https://pypi.org/project/rasterio/). [Tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/) and [imagecodecs](https://pypi.org/project/imagecodecs/) also work.

Answer (score 0):

The images are compressed with *"Adobe Deflate"* compression. You can tell that with `exiftool` like this:

```
exiftool YOURIMAGE.TIF
...
...
Compression                     : Adobe Deflate
...
```

As that is the case, you need to have `libtiff` installed to [decompress](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html) the images. You can tell that like this:

```
python3 -m PIL
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Pillow 9.1.1
Python 3.10.0 (v3.10.0:b494f5935c, Oct  4 2021, 14:59:19) [Clang 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Python modules loaded from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL
Binary modules loaded from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- PIL CORE support ok, compiled for 9.1.1
--- TKINTER support ok, loaded 8.6
--- FREETYPE2 support ok, loaded 2.12.1
--- LITTLECMS2 support ok, loaded 2.14
--- WEBP support ok, loaded 1.2.4
--- WEBP Transparency support ok
--- WEBPMUX support ok
--- WEBP Animation support ok
--- JPEG support ok, compiled for libjpeg-turbo 2.1.3
--- OPENJPEG (JPEG2000) support ok, loaded 2.5.0
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support ok, loaded 1.2.12
--- LIBTIFF support ok, loaded 4.4.0
--- RAQM (Bidirectional Text) support ok, loaded 0.9.0, fribidi 1.0.12, harfbuzz 5.3.1
*** LIBIMAGEQUANT (Quantization method) support not installed
--- XCB (X protocol) support ok
--------------------------------------------------------------------
BLP
Extensions: .blp
Features: open, save, encode
--------------------------------------------------------------------
...
...
...
```

So, I imagine you need to install `libtiff`. How you do that depends on your OS.